# AP que dá positivo em tudo, menos no correto e aceita o mais errado

Tags: debate

Acontece muito, principalmente usuários novatos, eles saem dando positivo em tudo que comentam. Pelo menos em casos como esse eu acredito que foi o próprio AP que deu os positivos nas respostas erradas:

[Como saber se o form é enviado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89105/como-saber-se-o-form-%C3%A9-enviado/89142#89142)

Mesmo eu apontando os erros visíveis em ambas respostas, o AP aceitou uma resposta com erro muito visível.

Eu percebi que ele aceitou antes de eu postar a minha resposta.

Eu fiquei muito incomodado em ver as duas respostas ruins e ao invés de dar negativo e "deixar pra lá", eu resolvi criar uma resposta.

Eu entendo que a política aqui é "deixa pra lá", deixar que o fluxo siga e com o tempo as pessoas vão definindo com positivos e negativos.

Eu até entendo isso até porque é inviável ter que avaliar tudo que se posta, mas acho que casos onde é bastante explícito e "pego em flagrante", poderíamos intervir.

Já tivemos discussões a respeito disso em diversas oportunidades mas não sei ao certo como ficou a resolução. Parece que há um consenso geral em "deixar pra lá", "deixar que o fluxo natural siga".

Então, deixa pra lá? rsrsrs

Tenho uma ligeira impressão de já saber a resposta e estar perdendo tempo com essa pergunta no meta. rsrs  Espero que não.

Comment: Mas ninguem sugeriu usar `@` no lugar do `isset()` haha xD

Comment: Geralmente o OP começa com [um problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82604/91) e acaba com [dois ou mais](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83792/91).

Comment: vendo esses 2 links que vc postou aí tenho uma conclusão.. hoje é sábado, eu vou é sair desse computador e curtir a praia. kkk

Comment: *"poderíamos intervir"*, fazer uma resposta boa, você já fez, não entendo porque não negativou as respostas ruins em vez de esperar *"o fluxo natural"*. Seu perfil mostra 205 votos a favor e 4 contra. Melhor deixar pra lá, né? Porque dá a impressão que quer que votemos contra por você...

Comment: Não entendi esse sarcasmo desnecessário, brasofilo. Não pedi para votarem negativo. Apenas estou consultando se não há outro meio de resolver esse tipo de situação sem "ferir" ninguém, mesmo os que postam errado. Sou contra a postura de atirar pedras (dando negativo) em alguém, pois rebaixa a pessoa que poderia ser um bom membro futuro na comunidade, mas acaba desistindo de participar aqui devido a atitudes de ogros que alguns tem. E também sou contra a política do "deixa pra lá". Sobre os pontos que tenho, na verdade nem sei quantos tenho ou para quê serve. Apenas participo pela comunidade.

Comment: O que eu costumo fazer é: dar -1, colocar um comentário se ainda não existir a dizer o porquê do -1. Explicar que dando -1 não é nada pessoal mas sim um reconhecimento da qualidade da resposta. Porque as perguntas e respostas são mesmo para ter +1, -1 ou 0 conforme o que se achar delas. Se ninguém coloca negativos em nada perde-se o objetivo do site de ter bom conteúdo.

Comment: Só para terminar dar -1 um não é ferir ninguém nem muito menos atitude de ogro (não sei o que isso é). Dar -1 é dar indicação ao autor que alguma coisa está errado. Será conveniente acompanhar o -1 de um comentário, mas mesmo isso não é obrigatório.

Comment: foi mal pelo azedume, Daniel, é que realmente me dá dissonância cognitiva danada: "como pode alguém ver um resposta ruim, e, pior, equivocada, e não tascar lá um voto negativo?".... Obviamente, é sua prerrogativa não votar -1, mas o site vive da votação separando conteúdo bom do ruim e você veio a público dizer "vi um troço ruim e não votei"... podia ter registrado minha discordância sem sarcasmo, mas já foi... o que não impede manifestar meus votos de uma excelente semana a você e demais participantes :)

Comment: E essa associação de voto negativo com tacar pedra ou atitude de ogro? Meus quase 10 mil votos negativos no SO me convertem num neandertal com acesso ao teclado :P

Comment: @brasofilo ou sarcástico ou comediante :P

Comment: Eu queria poder votar no primeiro comentário do @brasolfilo várias vezes, porque isto é algo que eu acho que falta de forma generalizada no site. Votos negativos não ferem ninguém. Não ferem nem a resposta. Mas uma resposta ruim pode eventualmente ferir alguém. Não dá para resolver problemas com filosofia, só com ações. A ação mais importante do site é o voto, incluindo o negativo. Não dá para fazer bife sem matar a vaca. Negativar sem motivo ou sem saber o que está fazendo, é ruim. Não negativar o que é ruim é deixar pra lá. O negativo existe para ser usado. Se não fosse, não existiria.

Comment: Tudo bem, brasofilo, agradeço os esclarecimentos. NMas como expliquei, não sou de dar negativo e também não sou contra quem o faz. Claro, sou contra os abusos e falta de bom senso.. mas não foi o caso.. enfim. Eu iria dar negativos nas respostas erradas após ver os comentários a essa pergunta aqui no meta. Apenas entenda que não vivo aqui 100% do meu tempo e teho pouca familiariadade no uso das ferramentas e as políticas de uso em si. Postei num fim de semana, não houve resposta e aguardei.. por isso não houve negativo meu..

Comment: mas uma coisa discordo muito é a sua interpretação distorcida sobre o que postei.. não concordo mesmo.. Claro que uma bobagem dessa não me fará ter nenhuma inimizade com ninguém aqui.. Bola pra frente.. Não postei nada de cunho pessoal, ou direcionado a alguem específico.. Acho que quem se sente incomodado é por que serviu a carapuça.. rsrs.. quem não se afeta, não se incomoda e compreende.. Pena que votaram negativo aqui... Esse é clássico exemplo de atitude de ogro.. votar negativo sem realmente entender o que houve

Comment: sarcástico ou comediante ou neandertal, Jorge B. kkk

Comment: bom, normalmente tento discutir o que a gente *faz*, não o que a gente *é*... bola pra frente total :)

Answer (score 7):

Me desculpe pelo tom meio desdenhoso da resposta, mas eu realmente não consigo ver o problema no caso que você apontou:

1. Uma pergunta é feita
2. A pergunta recebe respostas incorretas
3. Você fica incomodado com as respostas incorretas e decide escrever uma melhor
4. A resposta correta é a mais votada e marcada como correta pelo AP

Eu entendo que o AP deu upvotes dos quais você discorda, indo para respostas incorretas. Mas mesmo que upvotes não fossem prerrogativas de quem vota - assim como downvotes - e realmente não devessem de maneira alguma ser dados àquelas duas respostas. E mesmo que eles tenham realmente sido dados pelo AP, coisa que não tem como saber definitivamente. Mesmo que tudo isso seja verdade, esses são problemas muito inferiores ao produto final do que aconteceu.

Eu realmente não consigo ver como o que aconteceu de "errado" na pergunta pode ser sequer comparado a tudo que deu certo. A pergunta foi feita, recebeu uma resposta claramente boa e superior ao resto, que é muito mais bem votada que o resto, e foi marcada como correta.

De novo, não é ignorando o que foi dito, mas me parece que discutir a validade ou maneira correta de aplicar votos a favor ou contra me parece desnecessário num caso em que a comunidade agiu exatamente da maneira como se espera dela.

Comment: Concordo, parece ser uma caso de *gamificação* sendo levada ao extremo. No fim deu tudo certo lá. Inclusive as respostas ruins ficaram negativas (e -1 já é suficiente se não é um caso absurdo) e há comentários mostrando o problema.

Comment: Dos 4 pontos que vc mencionou, o 4 está errado. No momento que publiquei aqui, a minha resposta não era a marcada como correta. O usuário tinha marcado outra resposta errada. Como eu postei isso aqui no fim de semana, quase ninguem viu e de lá para cá as coisas foram mudando, foram dando positivos na minha resposta e marcaram a minha resposta como aceita. Eu até fiquei com receio que isso aqui fosse aocntecer. De mudar as repostas aceitas e as pessoas aqui não perceberem e entenderem errado.. Bingo.. o óbvio aconteceu..